# Can Calamarain Clouds go into warp?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Certain beings that dwell in open space, such as the Crystalline Entity and Nomad, can enter warp speeds freely. For other creatures, it's not so clear. Is there any evidence whatsoever that Calamarain Clouds can enter warp? Or are they confined to a small part of the galaxy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While not made explicit in the episode they appeared in, there is one piece of information that very strongly implies "yes":

They weren't recognized by the crew or the ship, and not seen until after Q was made human.

This means that once Q was made human, they must have then traveled to where he was for their revenge, somewhere inside Federation space - the Enterprise wasn't simply stopped in the same system they called home.  To make it within the time span in the episode, they have to be capable of traveling at warp or transwarp speeds in some way.

The novels are considered non-canon, but in the [Q Continuum novel](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Q_Continuum), it was mentioned explicitly that [they can travel at faster-than-light speeds](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Calamarain):

> Millennia ago, they were known as the Coulalakritous, but changed their name, perhaps as a result of their profoundly negative experiences with 0: a Q-like being who attempted to use them as his personal transport due his lacking the ability to travel faster-than-light.